# How to take Runtime inputs via user of html file to parse using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Like in code snippet below:

```
File input = new File("Example.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "Example.html");
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
           System.out.print("\nLinks: ");
```

All I want is user to input the filename of his choice instead of this hardcoded "Example.html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = args[0];
        File input = new File(filename);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        System.out.print("\nLinks: ");
    }

}
```

Then, to run it, do

```
java myClassFile.class FileNameIWant.html
```

That's what the `String[] args` in the `main` method is for.

Comment: Successfully running :) I am new to java development. Appreciate your kind help.